# Android Listview in FragmentList issue

Tags: android, listview

I'm having problems regarding how my list is.
I have navigation drawer and the content of my list start under that navigation drawer.
´
[Navigation Drawer and search view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jh2N7.png)

As you can see the search view is under "EBSPMA" wich is my company logo

Then i have another error, the process dialog only hide when i touch the screen even if the process is already done.

[ProgressDialod don't dismiss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sssk.png)

This is my fragment code

```
public class AtividadesFragment extends ListFragment {

public AtividadesFragment(){

}
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private static final String url = "http://xxx.xx.xx/xxxx/xxxx/xxx.php";
private ProgressDialog pg;
private List<Atividades> atividadesList = new ArrayList<>();
private ListView listView;
private AtividadesAdapter atividadesAdapter;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    atividadesAdapter = new AtividadesAdapter(getActivity(),atividadesList);
    listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(atividadesAdapter);
    pg = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    pg.setMessage("A carregar...");
    pg.show();

    JsonArrayRequest atividadesReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            //Ir buscar os dados
            VolleyLog.d("Dentro do atividadesReq", "ver");
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try{
                    JSONObject ati = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    Atividades ativ = new Atividades();
                    ativ.setAtividade(ati.getString("atividade"));
                    ativ.setLocal(ati.getString("local"));
                    java.sql.Date dat = java.sql.Date.valueOf(ati.getString("data"));
                    java.sql.Time hor = java.sql.Time.valueOf(ati.getString("hora"));
                    ativ.setData(dat);
                    ativ.setHora(hor);
                    atividadesList.add(ativ);
                }catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                atividadesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    },new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            hidePDialog();

        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(atividadesReq);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.atividades, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    hidePDialog();
}

private void hidePDialog() {
    if (pg != null) {
        pg.dismiss();
        pg = null;
    }
}
```

}

abd this is my layout xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/search_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="5dp" >
</ListView>
```

Comment: Well you never call `hidePDialog()` in onResponse unless there's error.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, yes hidePDialog() was missing, the second problem is resolved, how about the first one? Why do i have the search under the navigation drawer?

Comment: Hmm that is kind of strange. Why is it in the activity XML? Have you tried putting it inside the `toolbar` element instead?

Comment: Well, i didn't think like this, maybe it is the best thing to do, do you have na exemple please?